# 502 Error in Cloudfront behavior to redirect api requests to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have my frontend hosted on [www.printifyit.in](http://www.printifyit.in) and my ec2 instance on api.printifyit.in.

I created an origin in my CloudFront distribution which serves the frontend as follows
[image: origin in Cloudfront]

I am using Caddy as reverse proxy, so if i use HTTP only, i get 308 Permanent Redirect error as Caddy automatically redirects HTTP to HTTPS. Also i think HTTPS is preferred for security.

And for my Behavior, i am using /api/* path.

[image: Behavior in Cloudfront]

I keep getting this 502 Error
[image: 502 Error]

I have checked my SSL certificates for CloudFront and EC2, and both seem to be correct. I also have the api.printifyit.in in my SSL Certificate and CNAME of the CloudFront Distribution.
Do i need to use API gateway to achieve this?

Can anyone please help me out?
Thank You

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using images which represent textual information. Instead, to the question paste the output as text. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I thought it would be much easier with images as they can even see what I have selected. Yes. I should have pasted the 502 error as text.